# highcharts, how to prevent series hover event to cause hover event on nearest point(marker)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

By default if I hover mouse on series line (date-time chart) I get the hover event on nearest point of this series.

But I need to trigger hover event only on markers (points), but not on series.

If I do stopPropagation on series hover event, the point hover event is not triggered as well even on direct point hovering.

Can you please advice?

`plotOptions.series.stickyTracking = false` or `tooltip.snap = 0` didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Please add some code or even better a codepen example.

Comment: Can you please create some live fiddle demo or alternative example to get more idea?

Comment: I think checking whether you hovered on that point only and show tooltip accordingly would be tough, i suggest you can do alternate by using click event and turning off default tooltip. i prepared demo here. http://jsfiddle.net/418vgro4/

Comment: Here is the answer: findNearestPointBy. Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series/findnearestpointby/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve that, would be to set type of series to `scatter` and set `lineWidth` with some value. Also, disable `stickyTracking` and set `tooltip.snap` with a very small value (e.g. 1).

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cscatter%3E
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cscatter%3E.lineWidth
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cscatter%3E.stickyTracking
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.snap

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/02nnhp5x/